# WGET Multiple Lists To Corresponding Directories

Tags: xml, sed, grep, wget

I'm using WGET with lists to download multiple files with custom names, and need everything to go into custom directories.

What I'm starting with:
Just over 1000 XML files, each with a unique name in a single folder eg. speaker1.xml, speaker2.xml, etc. with formatting inside.
Sample:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Audios>
    <Audio>
        <Title>There is More</Title>
        <Url>http://www.somewebsite.com/modules/mydownloads/visit.php?lid=22295</Url>
        <Speaker>Man Speaking</Speaker>
        <Length>36.85Mb</Length>
        <Status>NOT_STARTED</Status>
        <isSelected>false</isSelected>
    </Audio>
</Audios>
```

I need to parse all these files so that only the title remains, without it's spaces, with .mp3 extension, followed by the link.

```
ThereisMore.mp3
http://www.somewebsite.com/modules/mydownloads/visit.php?lid=22295
```

I know how to use find/replace + RegEx for this, but only in an individual file.

Would Grep/Sed be what I need for this? If so, how?

Continuing with question 2,

My end goal is to use this to download a speaker's full set of mp3s and give them proper names:

```
while read url; do read filename; wget -O $filename $url; done < speaker1.xml
```

Now, I'm able to download all the links with custom names for a single file, but don't know how to accomplish this for multiple files.

I'll need everything to be saved into individual directories, with the speaker (or more properly, xml file) as the delimiter.

For example, processing speaker1.xml downloads all mp3 files for speaker1 to a directory called speaker1, the same for speaker2, 3, up to 1000+

I could put each .xml into a corresponding directory using

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" ; mv "$1" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
```

If I go that route, how would I get wget to loop through each xml within every directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I ended up getting it working.

I wrote a bash script to accomplish this task, I'll write out each line with explanation.

## replace </title> with .mp3

```
sed -i -- 's,</Title>,.mp3,g' *.xml
```

## remove ! from titles

```
sed -i -- 's,!,,g' *.xml
```

## remove ' from titles

```
sed -i "s,',,g" *.xml
```

## remove &amp; from titles

```
sed -i 's,&amp;,And,g' *.xml
```

## replace : with . in titles

```
sed -i -- 's,:,.,g' *.xml
```

## restore the : in http://

```
sed -i -- 's,p./,p:/,g' *.xml
```

## remove spaces from titles

```
sed -i -- 's, ,,g' *.xml
```

## remove leading title tag

```
sed -i -- 's,<Title>,,g' *.xml
```

## remove leading url tag

```
sed -i -- 's,<Url>,,g' *.xml
```

## remove all remaining < and > tags and everything in-between

```
sed -i 's,<.*>,,g' *.xml
```

## cleanup white space

```
sed -i '/^$/d' *.xml
```

## make a directory for all files with corresponding name, and move each .xml file to it's corresponding directory

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" ; mv "$1" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
```

## wget everything

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && while read filename; do read url; wget -O $filename $url; done < *.xml); done
```

## delete xml files

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && rm *.xml); done
```

## Final Product

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -- 's,</Title>,.mp3,g' *.xml
sed -i -- 's,!,,g' *.xml
sed -i "s,',,g" *.xml
sed -i -- 's,:,.,g' *.xml
sed -i -- 's,p./,p:/,g' *.xml
sed -i -- 's, ,,g' *.xml
sed -i -- 's,<Title>,,g' *.xml
sed -i -- 's,<Url>,,g' *.xml
sed -i 's,<.*>,,g' *.xml
sed -i '/^$/d' *.xml
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" ; mv "$1" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && while read filename; do read url; wget -O $filename $url; done < *.xml); done
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && rm *.xml); done
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. If it do what you want, remove all `echo` commands. I putted them, to displaying commands, which will be executed.

**Caution:** names of xml files shouldn't contain spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

# change this path to your xml files directory
xml_files_dir='xml_files'
# this directory will be contain all others speaker subdirectories
dir_for_all_speakers='speakers'

# 'echo' should be removed after testing, if script do what your want.
echo mkdir -p "$dir_for_all_speakers"

while read -r filename title url; do
    speaker_dir_path="${dir_for_all_speakers}/"$(basename "$filename" '.xml')

    if [ ! -d "$speaker_dir_path" ]; then 
        echo mkdir "$speaker_dir_path"
    fi  

    echo wget -O "${speaker_dir_path}/$title" "$url"
done < <(sed -rn '
    /<Title>/ {
        s/.*>(.*)<.*/\1.mp3/; s/ //g
        h
    }
    /<Url>/ {
        s/.*>(.*)<.*/\1/;
        H; g; F; p
    }
' "${xml_files_dir}/"*.xml | sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g')
```

**How it works:**

1. Makes main directory, where speaker's directories will be stored.
2. Takes all xml files and pass it to the first `sed`
3. `sed` searches 'Title' and 'Url' tags and removes all unneeded characters, leaves only values. Also it gets name of the current file by the `F` option:

   > **F** - Print out the file name of the current input file (with a trailing
   >   newline).
4. Pipes first `sed` output to the second `sed`. It merges every three lines to the one. filename.xml, songname.mp3, url are joined to the one line and delimited by spaces.
5. Now, we are have 1000 lines - one line per xml file. Each line contains all needed data. Passing them to the `while` loop.
6. `while` loop take the lines one by one and split them by spaces (this is, why filenames shouldn't contain spaces, it will screw our items count in the line). The `read` command is used for this.
7. Inside the `while` loop next happens - it cuts unneeded from the filename and gets speaker name. Creates directory for this speaker in the main dirctory (we made it on the step 1), if it doesn't exist. Downloads all speaker's files to there by the `wget` program.